# .htaccess redirect to a different subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

Please i need help to create a correct instruction in .htaccess to redirect old urls done in this way:

```
/it/cartelle/465-piquadro-signo-cartella-ca1744si.html
```

to

```
/it/valigeria/cartelle/465-piquadro-signo-cartella-ca1744si-ca1744si.html
```

in other words we have shifted all category cartelle under category valigeria.

Our .htaccess at the moment is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.it$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: That's the only .htaccess in the project?

Comment: Yes. We have only that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this if you want to redirect to a new URL:

```
 RedirectMatch /it/cartelle/(.*) /it/valigeria/cartelle/$1
```

If you want to keep the old url and just do an internal redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^/it/cartelle/(.*)$ /it/valigeria/cartelle/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But i have a doubt: At the moment both url are active. The problem is that we have duplicate content for google. So it's better use a redirect or canonical page?

Comment: If you are no longer going to use the old links, then use a 301 redirect. That will tell the search engines that the content has moved permanently and will thus update its search index and disregard the old links. RedirectMatch 301 /it/cartell .. etc